# how to display the item in the listbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to display the Items in the Listbox with Checkbox for each item. using jquery or asp.net mvc?

can any body tell me how to do this kind of thing?

thanks